# True being returned as false

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity and have a boolean getter that is always returning false. The Test Class below demonstrates what the problem is. If I use the interface the constructor always returns false, however when I specify which implementation I want then I get the correct result. I need to use the interface because I have a dozen implementations and I don't know which one I will need to use until runtime.

I've been stepping through the code all morning, when it comes to line 17 it goes to the correct instance, which has m_completed as true, but still gets assigned false. I'm hoping someone can see what the problem is cause right now I'm baffled.

EDIT: I've tried declaring the inherited class to also use the interface (`public class CityConstruction : Construction, IConstruction`) and that has solved the problem. I'm guessing that I have misunderstood how interfaces work, but I'm not sure why this solves the problem.

Test Class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public IConstruction my_construction1;
    public CityConstruction my_construction2;

    void Start()
    {
        my_construction = gameObject.GetComponent<CityConstruction>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        bool construction_completed1 = my_construction1.completed; //Always false
        bool construction_completed2 = my_construction2.completed; //Working
    }
}
```

Construction Interface:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public interface IConstruction
{
    bool completed { get; }
}
```

Construction:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class Construction : Structure, IConstruction
{
    private float m_construction;
    private int m_construction_needed;
    private int m_construction_per_second;
    private bool m_completed;               
    public bool completed { get { return m_completed; } }       

    /* UNITY METHODS */
    void Start () 
    {
        m_completed = false;
    }

    void Update () {
        if(m_construction >= m_construction_needed) {
            m_completed = true;
        } else {
            construct();
        }
    }

    private void construct() {
        m_construction = m_construction_per_second * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

City Construction:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CityConstruction : Construction
{
    private float m_construction;
    private int m_construction_needed;
    private float m_construction_per_second;
    private bool m_completed;               

    public bool completed { get { return m_completed; } }

    /* UNITY METHODS */
    void Start () 
    {
        m_construction = 0;
        m_construction_needed = 100;
        m_construction_per_second = 100;
        m_completed = false;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (m_construction >= m_construction_needed) {
            m_completed = true;
        } else {
            construct();
        }
    }

    /* PRIVATE METHODS */
    private void construct() {
        m_construction += m_construction_per_second * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in the getter itself? It seems likely that you actually have two instances of `Construction`

Comment: Your Construction Class is not compilebar, you have forgotten to specify type of complete property

Comment: please provide runnable code that reproduces the problem

Comment: `public complete { get { return m_complete; } }` isn't valid syntax (what is the `type` of `complet`?). And since you don't seem to be setting a value in the code you provided, I can only assume `m_complete` is using the default value for a `bool` (which is [false](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Is my_construction1 being instaniated before you try to get the value of completed in the following line:

```
bool construction_completed1 = my_construction1.completed; //Always false
```

If not, I would think that the get is just returning the default value of the property, which since it's a boolean would be false.